# React: state's boolean flag doesn't update fast enough

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, boolean

I keep a boolean flag named validationPassed in a state which I use in the if statement. If it's true, I allow axios request to happen. Before that, if-statement I call doValidation() which has a lot of if statements. If one of them fails, I setState of that boolean flag to `false`. In setState() I put console.log callback and it seems the boolean flag is successfully set to false but not immediately because if(this.state.validationPassed) passes when it shouldn't. I'm aware that React state is asynchronous. Tried to use prevState argument to toggle boolean's value but it didn't work. How do I make this work? Maybe there's another way to do validation without boolean flags?

```
    this.state = {

        validationPassed: true
    }
}

   this.doValidation(usernameFromUser, passwordFromUser)

   if(this.state.validationPassed){

    // axios call
   }

}

doValidation = (username, password) => {

    if(username.trim().length === 0){

          this.setState( {
            validationPassed: false }, () => {console.log(this.state.validationPassed)});
    }

    if(password.trim().length === 0){

          this.setState( {
            validationPassed: false }, () => {console.log(this.state.validationPassed)});
    } 

    if(username.trim().length < 8){

        this.setState( {
            validationPassed: false }, () => {console.log(this.state.validationPassed)});
    }

    if(username.trim().length > 20){

        this.setState( {
            validationPassed: false }, () => {console.log(this.state.validationPassed)});
    }

    if(password.trim().length < 8){

        this.setState( {
            validationPassed: false }, () => {console.log(this.state.validationPassed)});
        } 

    if(new RegExp("^(?!(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,}))").test(password)){

        this.setState( {
            validationPassed: false }, () => {console.log(this.state.validationPassed)});  
    }
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat outside the direct scope of your question, but if you've got state performing a validation check (and making an axios call when true), you may want to reverse the logic and default that state to false, instead. This will save you making an axios call as soon as the component is called, before the validation has actually checked the username and password criteria.

Comment: If you do validation right before making each call do you even need to keep the result in the state? Also what's the point of validating each field even when a previous failed?

Comment: You are right. I guess I was too fixated on state. I've now overwritten my validation with simple function that returns either true or false and everything works as I wanted!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

Read [this docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of react setState

```
this.setState(
  (currentStateValue)=> { value: !currentStateValue }, 
  (state)=>{console.log(state)}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest re-writing your validation making something like

```
const validationPassed = this.doValidation(usernameFromUser, passwordFromUser)
//save validationPassed into state if you need it elsewhere
if(validationPassed){
  // axios call
}

doValidation = (username, password) => 
  username.trim().length < 21
  && username.trim().length > 7
  && password.trim().length < 21
...
```